# ¿Qué quiere decir "piezas de a ocho"?

Tags: definiciones

En el contexto puede ser tonterías pero sospecho que puede significar mas.

> —Un día veré el mar —decía la niña, también como en los cuentos,
>   mientras pasaba la fregona por el suelo del puticlub6. Y soñaba con un
>   cocinero cojo y una isla, y un loro que gritaba no sé qué murga sobre
>   **piezas de a ocho**.

Comment: El loro de John Silver en *La isla del tesoro* repetía esa frase que aprendió cuando sacaban monedas de un galeón hundido. Es muy posible que se refiera a reales de a icho como dice @iván en su respuesta.

Comment: @blonfu puede añadir esa como segunda respuesta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La respuesta [la ha dado @iván](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23181/1674) pero por entrar un poco en contexto añado alguna información.

En la frase de ejemplo hablan  de un cocinero cojo, una isla, y un loro que grita algo relacionado con "piezas de a ocho". Claramente hace referencia al libro *La isla del tesoro* donde John Silver era un capitán pirata que fue cocinero y tenía una sola pierna, su loro repetía la frase "¡Piezas de a ocho!" que es algo que aprendió cuando sacaban galeones de la plata hundidos.

Los reales de a 8 eran de plata y era una moneda muy utilizada en aquellos tiempos de la piratería en  la zona del Caribe que trata este libro. Todo hace suponer que se refiere a los mencionados reales de a 8.

Answer (score 7):

Tal vez se refiere al [**Real de a 8**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_de_a_8):

> Las primeras monedas de 8 reales fueron instituidas en la Corona de Castilla por la reforma monetaria de 1497, llevada a cabo por los Reyes Católicos.
>
> Tras la conquista de México y Perú, los reales de a 8 se acuñaban en América con la denominación de real español y se transportaban a granel hacia España, haciendo este transporte un objetivo tentador para los piratas y corsarios del mar. Por otra parte, su uso también se extendió por el sudeste asiático, ...
>   ...
>   El real de a 8 se convirtió entonces en la divisa de más amplia difusión durante el periodo colonial en América, y por su elevado valor intrínseco así como por su fineza, se siguieron usando en Norteamérica y en el Sudeste asiático hasta el siglo XIX.

Comment: Soy Impresionado! Debe escribir las notas al fondo de los libros.